# Try to use usb4java highlevel librairie

Tags: java, usb, usb4java

So here it is my program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    UsbServices services = null;
    try {
        services = UsbHostManager.getUsbServices();
        hub = services.getRootUsbHub();
    } catch (SecurityException | UsbException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

And I have created the file 'javax.usb.properties' with inside:

```
javax.usb.services = org.usb4java.javax.Services
```

Like it's said in the documentation

At the moment of 'getRootUsbHub()' I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder
```

Does someone know why the method getRootUsbHub() doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss the `commons-lang3.jar` in your classpath. Download and add  it.